# send json object with httparty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, in-app-purchase, httparty

I'm trying to implement the in App purchase from within my iPhone app. To verify the receipt I need to send a json object to the iTunes server. Im trying to do this with the httparty plugin:

```
require 'httparty'

class ItunesVerification
  include HTTParty
  base_uri 'https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com'
  default_params :output => 'json'
  format :json
end


@result = ItunesVerification.post('/verifyReceipt', :query => {'receipt-data' => params[:receipt]})
```

When I do so, I keep getting a...

{"status":21002, "exception":"java.lang.NullPointerException"}

... error. I guess this is because of the not right implementation of the json object. The Object should have the structure: { "receipt-data" : "...." }... because of the - character in receipt-data it dosn't accept as :receipt-data identifyer...

How do I have to implement that right?

Thanks
Maechi

Comment: Can you post the json that the iTunes is expecting?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the solution:

I have to write :body instead of :query! Then it gets sent as a json object!

Markus